# How to identify duplicates UIPATH

Tags: datatable, uipath

Help me with this please.

I have this input column in a datatable

```
First Case:      Second Case:     Third Case:
Operation        Operation        Operation
C                C                V
C                C                V
V                C                V 
V                C                V 
C                C                V
C                C                V
V                C                V
C                C                V
V                C                V
```

And I want to know if the dt has C and V or just C or just V.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. The title says that you want to remove duplicates, but keep some (based on which condition?), but your question states that you want to determine whether a column has distinct values only.

Answer (score 2):

First you need 2 boolean variables to store the information if C and V exist or not. After that you need to loop through your dt using for each row activity. Inside foreach activity you can use an if activity with assign activty to compare row value with "C" or "V" and set the values of variables accordingly. Finally you can use the values of these variables to decide if your datatable has C and V or just C or just V.

[image]